# Are mapM and forM interchangeable?

Tags: haskell

As I understand `forM` is the same as `mapM`, only the arguments are reversed. 
Does this mean I could replace every `forM` with a `mapM` and the other way around, if I reverse the arguments I'm giving them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Indeed. `forM` is [literally](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#forM) just...

```
forM = flip mapM
```

... so it is the same except for the order of arguments. As a matter of style, `forM` looks nice when the function argument is a big block of code that you didn't bother giving a name to, as in:

```
-- Somewhere in a do-block...
results <- forM items $ \item -> do
    -- A do-block using `item`.
```

Side note: Specially if you are using the latest GHC (and thus the 4.8 version of the `base` package) I suggest replacing `mapM` and `forM` with the equivalent but more general `traverse` and `for` functions respectively. The Prelude in `base-4.8` exports `traverse`, while you can find `for` in `Data.Traversable`. Similarly, `Data.Foldable` offers `traverse_` and `for_`, which are strictly more general than `mapM_` and `forM_`.

Answer (score 8):

[Yes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#forM).  The definition in `base` is given as

```
forM  = flip mapM
```

With Haskell's equational reasoning this means that you can replace `forM` with `flip mapM`, then replace `flip` with its definition to get a normal looking `mapM` usage.  You can also follow this process backwards to go from `mapM` to `forM`.